# How do you compile a C++ program with multiple class files from OS X Terminal?

Tags: c++, class, compilation, terminal

I have tried doing

```
gcc [folderName] -o [executableName]
```

but that does not seem to work.

Comment: You have to compile the file with main, not the folder name, also gcc does not compile  C++, g++ does, also use clang++ on osx cause it is far more updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gcc is used for compiling C source files but for C++ you will need to use g++. As for the multiple files, just list them:

`g++ [list of all source files] -o [executableName]`

Also note that if you have installed gcc via xcode then it will be quite an old version. I would recommend using [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) instead as it is the compiler used by xcode and is kept up to date. It works pretty much the same as gcc so for your situation it would be:

`clang++ [list of all source files] -o [executableName]`

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use a Makefile as this will only compile files that have changed since the last build.

There is a nice tutorial on using make [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/makefiles.html)

Comment: pointing someone to a tutorial is not an answer, his command has errors you should say what is wrong