# How to compile a project with clases in Clang?

Tags: c++, compilation, clang

Seen this post:
[How do you compile a C++ program with multiple class files from OS X Terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18136319/how-do-you-compile-a-c-program-with-multiple-class-files-from-os-x-terminal)
I see that to compile with `gcc` a project with a class (with .h and .cpp) is easy as:

> g++ [list of all source files] -o [executableName]

And it actually works for me, but when i try to use `Clang`:

```
clang++-11 main.cpp Person.hpp Person.cpp -o main
```

I get:

```
clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files
```

NOTE: i know how to use `Makefile`'s, but i would like to have a quick way to compile in `Clang` like in `gcc`.

Comment: Please post the full clang command and its output

Comment: clang generally accepts the same command line syntax as g++.   I suspect you have made a typo in the clang command line, so if you don't spot it, please post the exact command line you used.

Comment: @anki @NateEldredge `clang++-11 main.cpp Person.hpp Person.cpp -o main` output: `clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files` Note that if i change "clang++-11" for "g++" it does compile

Comment: Try without including headers in the command line.

Comment: Don't *compile* the headers. They should be added via `#include` **only**.

Comment: Normally you just use `clang` and not `clang++-11` or anything specific. It'll figure out how to compile based on file extensions.

Comment: @RetiredNinja it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run `clang++-11 main.cpp Person.hpp Person.cpp -o main` with the header file, clang notices this and compiles the pre-compiled header "Person.pch", the default -o Person.pch is implied. Meanwhile you want getting yet another output file "main". Thus, clang complains it can't generate multiple output files, -o Person.pch and -o main.

Pre-compiled headers should be compiled separately.

```sh
clang++-11 Person.hpp
clang++-11 main.cpp Person.cpp -o main
```

The first step is not required, if skipped, no pre-compiled headers are used.